# How to remove/unbind rowSelect event from primefaces datatable

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

My main problem is I want to remove/unbind rowSelect, rowUnselect and rowDblselect events
  from datatable.

```
<p:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{myBean.myLazyModel}" var="var" 
        selection="#{myBean.selectedBean}" styleClass="uta-table lightgrey-table">

        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" id="select"
            style="width:2%;text-align:center" />

        <p:column id="namecol" headerText="Name" style="text-align:center">
            <p:inputText id="name" value="#{var.name}"
                styleClass="uta-textbox" style="text-align:center">
            </p:inputText>
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Assume the datatable has only 5 rows. Now I have selected first 4 rows by selecting checkbox (not by clicking on row). If I select 5th row
by clicking on the row(not selecting the checkbox) then the previous 4 rows are deselected resulting in only 5th row being selected. This is something concerns my client.

To avoid this problem I thought of unbinding/removing rowSelect event means I should be able to select a row only by selecting checkbox. This same problem persists in the primeface showcase also.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf

I tried to unbind/remove rowSelect event in the following two ways using jQuery css selectors

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function() {                        
                $('.lightgrey-table').off("rowSelect");
                $('.lightgrey-table').off("rowUnselect");
                $('.lightgrey-table').off("rowDblselect");

            });
</script>
```

second way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function() {                        
                $('.lightgrey-table').unbind("rowSelect");
                $('.lightgrey-table').unbind("rowUnselect");
                $('.lightgrey-table').unbind("rowDblselect");

            });
</script>
```

both didn't work for me. Could any one help me to resolve this.

thanks in advance guys

Comment: Its hard to understand what you're tryign to do ?

Comment: @Makky I have edited the question. I believe it is understandable now. Please let me know still you couldn't understand it. thanks for the response.

Comment: I strongly believe `p:column selectionMode="multiple"` should inactivate row-click selection, enabling it only for checkbox. However, it seems not to be in their priorities http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5206

Comment: @XtremeBiker Thanks for the link and as experts commented in the link our project can not go as Pro.

Answer (score 2):

You can design your columns this way

```
<p:datatable ...
   <p:column selectRow="false" ... />
</p:datatable>
```

In this way you can only select and unselect your rows by clicking on the checkbox.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious, but pressing the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key will allow multiple rows to be selected without affecting already selected rows.

If the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key option won't work for your client, you will need to turn the jQuery '$' shortcut back on to use it on a PrimeFaces app. Include the following JSF outputScript tags:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />

<h:outputScript target="head">
   $ = jQuery; // Put $ back so we can use jQuery in the default mode.
   $(document).ready(function() {
          // put your jQuery code here....
   });  </h:outputScript>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But we may need to do the same as stated in the problem which client gave as requirement. Lets see how it goes